# How can I check if a set of functions all return non null, in a single expression?

Tags: kotlin, null

Suppose I have three functions `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, all of which return nullable types.

```
fun foo(): Int? = 1
fun bar(): Int? = 2
fun baz(): Int? = 3
```

I want to call them, and if all them returns non-null, I want to compute a value from their return values.

I could do this with *statements*, like this:

```
val x = foo()
val y = bar()
val z = baz()
val result = if (x != null && y != null && z != null) x + y + z else null
```

However, I don't like the fact that I have to declare 3 extra variables that I can still access afterwards. By having 3 extra statements like this, it also means that I cannot use expression-bodied functions, if I were writing a function that returns `result`.

If I use `let`s instead:

```
val result = foo()?.let { x -> 
    bar()?.let { y -> 
        baz()?.let { z -> 
            x + y + z
        } 
    } 
}
```

This creates a deep nesting. If it were only one function, this would have been fine, but with 3 functions or more, this makes my intention of "call these three functions, if they are all non null, add them together" rather unclear.

How can I write this in a way that clearly conveys my intention, but also making it a single expression?

Comment: I don't believe there is a ready-to-use function that would do this. There is [listOfNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) but it won't help in your case because you wouldn't know if some null values were removed. I guess you could write your own vararg function for this.

Comment: @Joffrey I'm not necessarily looking for a ready-to-use function. I'm happy to write my own generic helper, but I can't think of any way to do it since it would require varargs type parameters. Note that the functions could return different types :)

Comment: Ah yes if those function calls can return different types, it's another story. Then I guess you may need to write multiple overloads with 2, 3, 4 arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are of different types, I think you need to write your own helper functions like these (different overloads needed for different numbers of parameters, because there's no other way for the compiler to know the types of the arguments):

```
inline fun <T : Any, U : Any, R> ifAllNotNull(t: T?, u: U?, block: (t: T, u: U) -> R): R? {
    return when {
        t != null && u != null -> block(t, u)
        else -> null
    }
}

inline fun <T : Any, U : Any, V : Any, R> ifAllNotNull(t: T?, u: U?, v: V?, block: (t: T, u: U, v: V) -> R): R? {
    return when {
        t != null && u != null && v != null -> block(t, u, v)
        else -> null
    }
}
```

```
val result = ifAllNotNull(foo(), bar(), baz()) { x, y, z -> x + y + z }
```

Note that all three parameters will be evaluated before any are checked for null.

---

Or if you want to do what you described (hiding the three variables after the result calculation) using just standard library functions, you can use `run` to limit the scope of the temporary variables:

```
val result = run {
    val x = foo()
    val y = bar()
    val z = baz()
    if (x != null && y != null && z != null) x + y + z else null
}
```

This would also give you the opportunity to short-circuit if you like:

```
val result = run {
    val x = foo() ?: return@run null
    val y = bar() ?: return@run null
    val z = baz() ?: return@run null
    x + y + z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = listOf(foo(), bar(), baz())
  .reduce { acc, i ->
    when {
      acc == null || i == null -> null
      else                     -> acc + i
    }
  }
```

Or as function:

```
fun <T> apply(operation: (T, T) -> T, vararg values: T?): T? {
  return values
    .reduce { acc, i ->
      when {
        acc == null || i == null -> null
        else                     -> operation(acc, i)
      }
    }
}

val result = apply({ x, y -> x + y }, foo(), bar(), baz())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out all `null`-values and only apply an operation on the list, if it did not shrink in size, e.g.:

```kotlin
fun sumIfNoneNull(values: List<Int?>): Int? = values
    .filterNotNull()
    .takeIf { it.size == values.size }
    ?.sum()
```

One may generalize this further, e.g.:

```kotlin
fun <T, R> List<T>.foldIfNoneNull(
    initial: R,
    operation: (acc: R, T) -> R
): R? = this
    .filterNotNull()
    .takeIf { nonNullList -> nonNullList.size == this.size }
    ?.fold(initial, operation)
```

You may use this like any other `fold`, e.g.:

```kotlin
listOf(foo(), bar(), baz()).foldIfNoneNull(0) { acc, cur -> acc + cur }
```